# ROS Answers SE migration: Make a 2D map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have another problem that need your help,

I built a data.bag using rosbag as [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData#record) with transform

### Heading

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
ros::init(argc, argv, "urca_hokuyo_tf");
ros::NodeHandle n;

ros::Rate r(100);

tf::TransformBroadcaster broadcaster;

while(n.ok()){
broadcaster.sendTransform(
tf::StampedTransform(
tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), tf::Vector3(0.1, 0.0, 0.2)),
ros::Time::now(),"base_link", "hokuyo_scan"));
r.sleep();
}
}

, but when i use rosrun gmapping slam.. and rosbag play and rosrun map_sever map_saver. I do not create a map.

Please, show me how can i fix it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249512/make-a-2d-map/) by [ThiemPHAM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28524/thiempham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, make sure whether the bag file you have recorded has data or it is empty. This can be done by

> rosbag play --clock data.bag

Then echo the topic to check whether the bag file is publishing data.

---

Originally posted by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) with karma: 243 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0